# Virtual layer error in QField - Android

Tags: qfield

I defined some virtual layers in my QGIS project. Running a compiled QField in Ubuntu environment, virtual layers works fine. But using QField in Android (last official from playstore or the compiled apk from Ubuntu) virtual layers in the project cannot be loaded and 'invalid data provider virtual' message appears.

Is it possible to use virtual layers with QField in Android?

Answer (score 1):

The virtual layer provider has not been packaged with qfield.
Starting from version [1.1.0](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v1.1.0) this provider is shipped with QField.